# SQL Collation issue between SQL 2000 and SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, collation

I am querying a sql 2000 database on a sql 2008 database (linked server) and in the linked server i have a data with accents in. However when i query the 2008 database the accents appear correctly and as expected. But when i run the query on sql 2000 database the data is not showing correctly.

> SQL 2000 Collation - SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
>
> SQL 2008 Collation - SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2

I have attempted to add "COLLATE" to my queries however it is just not showing the data correctly. 
Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: do you mean the accents are stripped from the results?  Or is the sort order incorrect?

Comment: So the correct data is "Í" and the incorrect is showing "Ö". So its not like its missing the accent it is just getting the data completely wrong.

Comment: Check if the linked server is marked as "collation compatible" (it should be off).

Comment: Got the DBA to check this setting and i can confirm this setting is set to off. We did also try it with it ticked too but that made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the issue was that the data types for the columns were varchar when they needed to be nvarchar. By dropping the table and recreating it with the correct data type this resolved my issue.

Comment: Why not simply using an `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN`?